# Ansible command to trigger registration on another server

Tags: ansible

I can't find any documentation on how to include a secondary server in a playbook.

If for instance, I want to install sssd on SERVERA and register with a FreeIPA server.

On the FreeIPA server (only), I need to:

- get a Kerberos ticket (via kinit)
- check if SERVERA is already in IPA instance
- delete SERVERA from IPA if true

Since this is an installation playbook run against SERVERA, it doesn't seem right to include the IPA server in the hostlist...but nor can I see any "third party servers" module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are searching for the **delegate_to** option, which allows you to delegate a task to a host that is not in the hostlist.

Often used to run things on the localhost (host running ansible), it can also be used to push a task to a host not in hostlist. The host has to be in the inventory file though.

Example:

```
- name: Ping the other host
  ping:
  delegate_to: otherhost.com # This is where you set it
```

More info: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation